# Is it possible to access the infrared camera on iPhone X?

Tags: iphone-x, infrared

According to this picture:

[image: iPhone X sensors]

the iPhone X has an infrared camera. It is primarily used for face detection but there are other uses for infrared. Can it be accessed directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure about infrared but to read the depth information from the iPhone X TrueDepth camera, we can use the AVDepthData class and related APIs. [Here's a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/168312/image-depth-maps-tutorial-ios-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

not via the approved iOS API library calls. But undocumented API should be possible if you guess how to do it.

Comment: I'd love to see more details about the undocumented APIs. I'm not planning an App Store app, I just want to play with it!

Comment: Any updates on ways to access this API, documented or otherwise?

Answer (score -1):

The company, reallusion.com makes a 3D animation product called 'iclone 7' which interfaces with the iPhone infrared camera. Try contacting them about how they do it. if not proprietary, they might at least give you a clue.

Comment: What have you seen that leads you to believe that the iclone product uses the iPhone's infrared camera?