# capturing infrared pics on iPhone X front camera.

Tags: iphone, swift, camera, iphone-x, infrared

Definitely there is an infrared camera on iPhone X. I wonder, if it possible to capture photo/video from it using official instruments and swift. All apple official docs are only about using face id or measuring depth. And I can't find any info about possibility to do this.

P.s. there is only one stack overflow question: [Is it possible to access the infrared camera on iPhone X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190065/is-it-possible-to-access-the-infrared-camera-on-iphone-x).
But there is no clear answer. Thanks a lot